# Install rlwrap on a Mac, OS X 10.7.3

Tags: mac, apt, lion

I'm new to using a Mac and have come from developing in the land of Ubuntu and Windoze before that. 
I'm trying to install **rlwrap**. I read that first I need to install XCode and then Fink. Ok, I got through that. Now I run
    `sudo apt-get install rlwrap`
and I get
    `E: Couldn't find package rlwrap`.

I'm guessing I need to add another repository to fink but I cannot figure out, 1, what repository to add and, 2, where I add that.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several projects out there package open source software for OS X.  The `fink` project is one of them, but I'm not sure how active it is anymore.

Alternatives to fink include [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  With MacPorts installed on my system, I can:

```
$ sudo port install rlwrap
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for rlwrap
--->  Fetching archive for rlwrap
--->  Attempting to fetch rlwrap-0.37_1.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/rlwrap
--->  Fetching rlwrap
--->  Attempting to fetch rlwrap-0.37.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/rlwrap
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for rlwrap
--->  Extracting rlwrap
--->  Configuring rlwrap
--->  Building rlwrap
--->  Staging rlwrap into destroot
--->  Installing rlwrap @0.37_1
--->  Activating rlwrap @0.37_1
--->  Cleaning rlwrap
```

And then:

```
$ rlwrap  --version
rlwrap 0.37
```

Comment: awesome. I'm in business. I guess I just jumped on the first bus that came by (fink) and should've done little more research. Thanks